# how to handle HTREEITEM

Tags: winapi

The handle is defined in CommCtrl.h (part of the Windows SDK) like this:

```
struct _TREEITEM;
typedef struct _TREEITEM *HTREEITEM;
```

I know It's  an opaque handle,But I do not know how to get the information of the item,such as it`s text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get information about an `HTREEITEM` using [`TreeView_GetItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773841.aspx):

> Retrieves some or all of a tree-view item's attributes. You can use this macro or send the [TVM_GETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773596.aspx) message explicitly.

You can retrieve the text like this:

```
TVITEM item = {0};
item.hItem = ht; // <-- the HTREEITEM goes here
TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
item.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
item.pszText = buf;
item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
TreeView_GetItem(hTreeView, &item);
```

Or:

```
TVITEMW item = {0};
item.hItem = ht; // <-- the HTREEITEM goes here
WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
item.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
item.pszText = buf;
item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETITEMW, 0, (LPARAM)&item);
```